# Do I need a 32 bit version for my old PC?

Tags: 32-bit

I'm new to computers in general. I checked the system and it said 32 bit/pixels. I don't know if pixels is different than bit, but that's what it said.

I want to know if there is either a 32 bit version or if I need a different OS. It currently has winXP as OS. It has 1.5 GB mem.
Celeron d inside. It's a gateway.
EDIT:I CHECKED THE DRIVES AND IT WAS MY DADS OLD PC. IT HAS UBUNTU ONE ON IT.  IF I MOVE A WINDOW IT SHAKES IT. KINDA LIT IMA KEEP IT.

Comment: I have removed your phone number. Please don't do that. You don't know if we are nice people or not.

Comment: Exact CPU model is needed. What is the RAM configuration? Can it be increased to 4+ Gb?

Comment: When you said "it's a gateway", did you meant it is a computer from the manufacturer "Gateway" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway,_Inc.) that is no longer in business?

Comment: As others have said, you haven't given us enough detail to provide meaningful & helpful answers. I did use a `hp d220mt (dr159p), (celeron 2ghz, 1gb (732mb useable), 82845G/GL Brookdale-G/GE (i915))` in some testing, it ran Lubuntu 18.04 LTS the best (*better than Debian 10/Buster LXDE which surprised me*), but I generally ignored it as it was slower than pentium M laptops, or pentium 4 desktops (which weren't sharing RAM with graphics as well as having better cpus).  Lubuntu 18.04 I still use on a thinkpad t43 which has 1.5gb of RAM, but I do limit how I use it.

Comment: Based on the edit history of this question - You can upload a screenshot in imgur and then post the link here. You would be able to post screenshots directly once you gain some [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: The closest CPU detail I found was https://www.cnet.com/products/gateway-e-1500d/specs/ which implies x86_64/amd64 capable, meaning you're not limited to i386/x86/32-bit IF that matches your CPU. Either way celeron's are cut-down machines and best match a more expensive cpu of a generation before, so I'm not sure you'll get great performance; but it'll depend on what you use it for (like the ibm t43, & t42p I use; they do the jobs I have for them perfectly, but there are loads of tasks I'd avoid doing on them - using other boxes).

Answer (score 4):

No, 32 bit/pixels is not related to whether the computer is 32-bit or 64-bit.
You need to know your exact processor model. The very first Celeron D processors, from June 2004 (known as "Prescott") were 32-bit. The later generation of Celeron D processors (known as "Cedar Mill") were 64-bit.

[Here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001121.htm#earlier-windows-versions) I found an information how you can from under Windows XP determine if your processor is 32-bit or 64-bit. Note that this is different from whether you are running a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system. You can run a 32-bit OS even if your processor is 64-bit.

However, 1,5 GB seems to be very little to run Ubuntu with a full graphical desktop. Someone suggested Lubuntu in the comments - or, if you don't need a graphics environment, you can try a minimal installation of Ubuntu Server, which has no GUI.

You can also try a completely other distribution, not any Ubuntu variant, but that is off-topic for this board.

Comment: Yes it's manufactured by gateway the company. It can only hold two slots of ram and the biggest I have Is a 1 GB and a 512mb in there. Guiverc, your going a lil too fast for me. The model is e-1500 D SB. It was manufactured in 06. I think it has a floppy drive.